# (Function) Return JSON Objects from Each Loop, into Variable using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array of objects saved in localstorage.

Here is a sample of the array of objects:

```
[{"mls":"1266159","addr":"13556 S TUSCALEE ,  Draper, UT 84020","price":"$1499000","description":"Bds:  7  | Ba:  7  |  10376 Sqft."},{"mls":"1279829","addr":"12927 S SALZ ,  Draper, UT 84020","price":"$779000","description":"Bds:  4  | Ba:  4  |  5857 Sqft."},{"mls":"1279960","addr":"14226 S CANYON VINE E,  Draper, UT 84020","price":"$1899000","description":"Bds:  7  | Ba:  8  |  10015 Sqft."}]
```

I have written a function to get the array, then run an "each" loop to iterate over the objects and return all objects in the array, in the specified format.

Function:

```
function getReportStore() {
        var rs = localStorage.getItem("reportStore");
        //console.log("Report Store: "+rs);
        if((rs != null) && (rs != '')){
            var r = JSON.parse(rs);
            $.each(r, function (k, v) {
                return "MLS: "+v.mls+" Address: "+v.addr+" Price: "+v.price+"    Description: "+v.description;
            });
        }
    }
```

Trying to call function, and return the data into a variable...

```
var p = getReportStore();
```

Now use the variable...

```
var report = "Properties Viewed: " + p;
console.log("The Report: "+report);
```

The problem, is that when I try and execute the function in order to use the returned objects as a variable, it comes back as "undefined".

Thank you in advance for your suggestions/assistance/guidance/etc!

Comment: Use var somevar = JSON.stringify(report); and then print somevar

Comment: where exactly is it undefined? .... what is the output of getReportStore? this function does not return anything, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are not returning anything from your function. You are returning from the inner higher order $.each function but this does not return from getReportStore().

Try it like this :

```
function getReportStore() {
    var rs = localStorage.getItem("reportStore");
    //console.log("Report Store: "+rs);
    if((rs != null) && (rs != '')){
        var r = JSON.parse(rs);
        return r.map(function (v) {
            return "MLS: " +v.mls +
                " Address: "+v.addr +
                " Price: "+v.price +
                "    Description: " + v.description;

        }).join('\n');
    }
    return "";
}
```

note: I replaced jquery $.each with standard array map

Comment: good luck. btw. I added a join because map (and $.each)  will return an array. I presume you want to join them together. Otherwise you could leave it out and get an array back

Comment: Odd... Instead of returning undefined, it returned blank...?

Comment: returns blank if ((rs != null) && (rs != '')) is not true. Are you sure localstorage contains something? probably want to uncomment that console.log

Comment: haha I had deleted the localstorage. I will also add and else clause to create localstorage if it doesn't exist. Thank you!